# C# DataGridView - Choosing which columns to display

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where its data is retrieved from a MySQL database. How do I only show columns to display?
One way is to use the `Visible` property of the `Columns` object and set `dgv.Columns["col"].Visible = false;`

But I want to do it the other way around. I want to *choose which columns to display*, *not choose which columns to hide*. Something like this:
`dgv.Columns["col"].Display= true;`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`. This will require you to specifically set `myColumn.Visible = true` for columns you would like to display.

Comment: Okay, but how do I add the columns now? When I try to reference the columns, I get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: With this method you would need to specifically add all columns you would like to be displayed within the DataGridView. You can do this problematically and/or with markup. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-columns-in-the-datagrid-using-the-designer

Answer (score 0):

how about first setting all columns to invisible and then setting the ones you want to visible?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
     dgv.Columns[i].Visible = false;
}

     dgv.Columns["this_one_i_want_to_see"].Visible = true;
     dgv.Columns["this_one_i_want_to_see_too"].Visible = true;
```